# tomcat 8 not running on ubuntu

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu

Set up a clean ubuntu 14.04 on digitalocean, installed java 8 and tomcat 8 (with wget gz) and set CATALINA_HOME and JAVA_HOME.

ran startup.sh fine but the IP:8080 does not load anything.
running shutdown.sh tells me that Tomcat isn't running at all...

```
root@ADWBQ:~# $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
root@ADWBQ:~# $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Nov 06, 2015 1:18:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Could not contact localhost:8005. Tomcat may not be running.
Nov 06, 2015 1:18:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Catalina.stop:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:450)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:400)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:487)
```

What am I doing wrong?

edit:

```
root@ADWBQ:~# lsof -i :8080
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    734 root   46u  IPv6  13386      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

edit2:

```
root@ADWBQ:~# $JAVA_HOME/bin/jps
788 Jps
734 Bootstrap
```

edit3:

```
root@ADWBQ:~# curl -v localhost:8080
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:8080/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
```

edit4
I changed the shutdown server port to 8080, now running shutdown.sh is perfectly fine. But I still can't access the index.jsp after startup.sh

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8080" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

catalina.2015-11-06.log:

```
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.196 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.198 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Oct 7 2015 18:25:21 UTC
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.198 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.28.0
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.198 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.198 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.2.0-16-generic
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.198 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.199 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.199 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_66-b17
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.201 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.201 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/tomcat
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.201 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.209 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.209 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.209 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat/endorsed
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.210 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.210 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.211 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.211 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.647 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.683 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.688 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.712 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.718 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1819 ms
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.761 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.762 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
06-Nov-2015 02:30:32.776 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager
```

Comment: Post please jps output

Comment: can you post a `lsof -i :8080` after a  startup?

Comment: Your `lsof -i :8080` shows a java process listening to *:8080, and jps confirms it's tomcat. You may be using the wrong IP in your test. What does a `curl -v localhost:8080` gives you?

Comment: @RC. posted to edit3, thanks!

Comment: Looks like all is fine

Comment: @StrangerintheQ added output to edit 2, thanks!

Comment: @StrangerintheQ the page still can't be accessed, though...

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks like Tomcat is trying to connect to :8005

Comment: Paste your server.xml file

Comment: @Altmish-E-Azam added to edit4, thanks!

Comment: @seanchua Tomcat is running?? Is there only issue while shutdown?? M i right?

Comment: @Altmish-E-Azam I have no idea if it is actually running or not, since I cannot load the index.jsp in my browser.

Comment: umm. shouldn't the first thing be checking out tomcat logs? Why aren't those even mentioned? Check them out and add any relevant information from them to the question.

Comment: @seanchua.. you have to trace all Catalina log to find out the issue so first of all tail the Catalina logs on one terminal and try to start tomcat from another terminal and paste catalina logs here

Comment: @Altmish-E-Azam added logs at the bottom

Comment: @seanchua.. have you tried to access your application?? As in logs no one app had been loaded.. try to access `http://localhost:8080/manager/html` if it's working then there is issue to load you web application.  And try one more thing change the `shutdown` port `8080` to `8005`

Comment: @Altmish-E-Azam it's working...I'm looking to see if Ubuntu has inbound connections allowed at all

Comment: @seanchua .....you mean `http://localhost:8080/manager/html` is working?

Comment: @Altmish-E-Azam yes, that works using curl -v

Comment: so there is no issue in tomcat you need to check you web application for the same or try to deploye your web app using html manager.